# Partial Redirection with additional Piping

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, io-redirection

There's an auto generated file on a remote location that is constantly changing, I can only view the remote file via `ssh user@ip cat luckyNumbers` it tells me today's lucky numbers and also passes along a secret encrypted message.

```
Today's lucky number are 
1 2 3 
asdsa@!#SAxAaas 21gv3sad ASD@!#
```

My goal is to

- redirect the lucky numbers `1 2 3` into luckynumbers.txt and then
- Pipe the remainder of the file into my program `decoder`
- I would like to do this without saving the entire file, or making a second request for the file

I'm not sure if its even possible to split a data stream like this.

Comment: What commands are you allowed to use?

Comment: There are no restrictions on commands from the client side, the only limitations are that the file is read via ssh user@ip cat luckyNumbers, as well as not making a second request or saving the entire file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few ways to write line 2 of stdin to a specific file while sending all other lines to stdout.

Using sed:

```
ssh remotehost cat luckynumbers |
sed -e '2 { w luckynumbers.txt
            d
          }' |
decoder
```

Using awk:

```
ssh remotehost cat luckynumbers |
awk 'NR == 2 { print > "luckynumbers.txt" }
     NR != 2 { print }' |
decoder
```

Note that, if the last line of the input does not end in a newline, awk will probably add one.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat luckynumber | tail -q -n 2 | head -q -n 1 > luckynumbers.txt && cat luckynumber | tail -w -n 1 | decoder
```

- will pick up the contents of *luckynumber*
- quietly (no citation of source file) pluck out the last two lines
- send the next to last line to *luckynumbers.txt*
- pick up the contents of *luckynumber* again
- quickly pluck out only the last line
- and pipe it to *decoder*

I know it makes a second request for the file, and will try to improve on this so its replacement does not make a second request (maybe with [tee](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html)), but for now, this is what I've got.

Comment: `cat luckynumber | tee luckynumbers.txt | tail -q -n 1 > decoder & A MIRACLE HAPPENS HERE`. Stay tuned for something like `tail -q -n 2 < luckynumbers.txt &&  head -q -n 1 > luckynumbers.txt` to finish this.